# Mikrotik RB951G-2HnD - wi-fi drops or hangs connections

Tags: router, wifi, mikrotik, wireless-bridge

We've bought Mikrotik RB951G-2HnD in our company (about 20 - 25 clients in network) with 50 Mbps channel from the ISP-side. Mikrotik Wireless drops connection or getting very low speed often as more people are connected via Wi-Fi (since 10 people on a Wi-Fi we're experiencing problems):

https://monosnap.com/file/kYWbyTkgCzDrcWJtkH5Mve25o6deFR.png

Configuration is following:

https://monosnap.com/file/QoP2lsJzYfy0fBdAOJTX6XcPWeJFjq.png

What is the problem with this router?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no problem with the router.

WiFi does not work ok when many users are connected to the same Access Point.

Add to that the fact that the 2.4GHz band is heavily saturated so you may have a log of noise even though you have good signals on all clients.

You could try changing the frequency to see if you can get better performance.

Also keep in mind the Hidden Node problem with WiFi.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hidden_node_problem

> In wireless networking, the hidden node problem or hidden terminal
>   problem occurs when a node is visible from a wireless access point
>   (AP), but not from other nodes communicating with that AP. This leads
>   to difficulties in media access control.

[image]

You may be able to handle the Hidden Node problem by enable CTS/RCS on the Access Point, but I am afraid that it won't do much if that's your root of the problem.

Comment: Also you could try to enable the `CCQ` column in the Wireless Registration Table window. If CCQ is near 90-100 then the quality of the connection is good. If the CCQ is bellow 90 then you may have interference problems. Also check the `IP Throughput` column which calculates the max bandwidth each client can attain.

Comment: So, now we have 25 users in our network (all are laptops) , I don't think that it's too much for this router. Or am I wrong?

Comment: It isn't a matter of router. The bottleneck is not on the router but in the 'air'. The WiFi protocols do not perform well with multiple/concurrent users. There is not much you can do with standard laptops (hence standard 802.11b/g/n). There are a few technologies out there that solve this issue with multiple connected users, but require specialized software/hardware on both ends (eg: Mikrotik/NV2, Ubiquiti/TDMA, etc).

Comment: What if we buy other router or AP? What would you recommend to add to existing router in order to releave the load pressure on the AP?